# How to send request to the server from different client IP for every user in Visual studio load testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I am testing a web application using visual studio load testing by providing 100virtual user.
 when I do this each user is sending request from same client IP. my requirement is that each user should send request from different IP. Is there any way to do this like creating virtual IPs and assigning it to each virtual user so that each can request the server from different clients presnets on different IPs.

Any body have idea to do this. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one would configure multiple IPs at the OS/network level and then configure the testing tool to use them. On Windows, you would follow steps like this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722518.aspx) to configure multiple IPs on your network adapter (be sure to check with your network admin, first!).

Then you'll need to configure the load testing software to use those IPs. Sorry, I don't know how to do that in VS. In our tool it is a simple matter of checking some options in the load generator UI.